# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre wait() y sleep() en Java?

Tags: java, hilos, multitasking

En mi aplicación estoy manejando distintos hilos, los cuales deben "dormir" X segundos. He notado que usando ambos métodos el hilo duerme.

¿La diferencia es que con `Thread.sleep(5000);` duermo el hilo principal y con `hilo.wait()` puedo hacer dormir cualquier otro hilo creado? ¿Estoy en lo correcto? Si no es así agradeceré mucho sus explicaciones.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Éstas son las diferencias entre sleep(int milis) y wait(int milis)

[image: Tabla diferencias entre sleep y wait]

`wait()` sin parámetro de milis se comporta exáctamente como si simplemente llamase a `wait(0)`

No es una diferencia el uso que hacen del hilo o el procesador. Como demuestra el código que pongo al final. Ambos hacen una espera no ocupada sin consumir recursos (en una buena máquina virtual, cualquiera de los dos podría hacer una espera ocupada en una máquina virtual no optimizada).

Una diferencia muy importante son los **despertares espúreos**. Los cuales afectan a `wait` pero no a `sleep`. Un `wait` puede terminar en cualquier momento, sin motivo ni justificación, y es responsabilidad del programador tener esto en cuenta.

En lo que son iguales es en que **ambos duermen al hilo en que se ha ejecutado** la llamada a `wait` o `sleep`. Ninguno sirve para dormir al hilo principal (excepto si se ejecutan en el hilo principal).

## Conclusión :

Usa sleep para esperar tiempo.
Los wait son para otra cosa (sincronización) y sufren de despertares espúreos.

### Código demostración uso CPU

En mi máquina se ejecuta en 10-13 segundos tanto con `USAR_SLEEP` a `true` como a `false`.

```
class Test extends Thread {

    static final boolean USAR_SLEEP = false;
    static final int NUM_THREADS = 20000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Test[] thread = new Test[NUM_THREADS];
            for (int n = 0; n < NUM_THREADS; ++n) {
                thread[n] = new Test();
                thread[n].start();
            }
            int m = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 100000000; ++n) {
                m = m * 23 + n;
            }
            if ( !USAR_SLEEP )
            {
                for ( Test t : thread )
                {
                    synchronized( t.cerrojoImplicito )
                    {
                        t.cerrojoImplicito.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
            for (Test t : thread) {
                t.join();
            }
    }

    public Object cerrojoImplicito = new Object();
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (USAR_SLEEP) {
                sleep(5000);
            } else {
                synchronized (cerrojoImplicito) {
                    cerrojoImplicito.wait(5000);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrumpido");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias estimado, excelente colaboración.

Answer (score 7):

Un `wait` puede ser "despertado" por otro proceso llamando `notify` en el monitor que está siendo atendido, mientras que un `sleep` no. También `wait` (y `notify`) debe suceder en un bloque `synchronized` sobre el objeto de monitor mientras que `sleep` no.

```
Object mon = ...;
synchronized (mon) {
    mon.wait();
}
```

En este punto, el hilo que se está ejecutando actualmente espera y libera el monitor. Otro hilo puede hacer:

```
synchronized (mon) { 
     mon.notify(); 
}
```

(En el mismo objeto `mon` ) y el primer hilo (suponiendo que es el único hilo en espera en el monitor) puede despertar.

Existe una pregunta con una gran cantidad de respuestas en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep
respuesta realizada por el usuario [oxbow-lakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbow-lakes) (esto para respetar la licencia de SO)

Comment: si, veo que copiaste y pegaste la respuesta xD pero gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Es un placer, mucha de la información se encuentra actualmente en StackOverflow, se puede ayudar a traducir para replicarla aquí, saludos.

Comment: Sugerencia : añade los despertares espúreos, es una diferencia muy importante entre sleep y wait.

Answer (score 7):

`wait()` no es un método para esperar un tiempo, es parte de una primitiva de sincronización.

La primitiva de sincronización en cuestión, son los monitores. Un monitor, básicamente es un mútex más una variable de condición.

En Java, cada objeto tiene un monitor. Se adquiere el mútex del monitor con `synchronized(objeto) {`, y el mútex se libera cuando termina el bloque de código, con el correspondiente  `}`.

Mientras está adquirido el mútex, se pueden hacer operaciones con la variable de condición adecuada:

- Se puede esperar a que se produzca una condición:

  `while (!condicion) { objeto.wait(); }`

  Antes de poner el hilo en espera, se libera el mútex, para que otros hilos puedan realizar operaciones con la variable de condición. Cuando se despierta intenta readquirir el mútex.
- Se puede notificar que se ha producido la condición, pidiendo que se despierte uno de los hilos en espera:

  `objeto.notify();`
- Se puede notificar que se ha producido la condición, pidiendo que se despierte todos los hilos en espera:

  `objeto.notifyAll();`

Un ejemplo sería una cola con un hilo productor, y un hilo consumidor. La cola se protegería con el monitor. El consumidor iría desencolando elementos, si la cola esta vacía, se pondría a esperar con un `wait()`. El productor añadiría elementos a la cola, notificando a posibles consumidores que la cola ya no está vacía.

Cuando se espera a que se produzca una condición, es importante comprobar la condición en un bucle.

Comment: Sugerencia : añade los despertares espúreos, es una diferencia muy importante entre sleep y wait

Answer (score 4):

En el caso de `Thread.sleep()` no es el hilo principal el que se suspende sino el actual, es decir aquel que está ejecutando justamente esa línea de código.

En el caso de `wait()` no es a un hilo al que se hace el `wait` sino a un objeto que sirva para la sincronización.

La sobrecarga que mencionas del método [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) está definido en la clase `Object` así

```
public final void wait() throws InterruptedException
```

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object. In other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call `wait(0)`.

Traducción:

> Hace que el hilo actual espere hasta que otro hilo invoque el método `notify()` o `notifyAll()` en este objeto. En otras palabras se comporta exactamente como si se hubiera llamado a `wait(0)`.

Por lo tanto la única manera de resumir la ejecución del hilo (con esta sobrecarga ya que hay otra a la que le pasas un timeout) es utilizar `Object.notify` o  `Object.notifyAll`.

Si necesitas suspender un hilo hasta que otro lo despierte puedes usar `object.wait()` , si en cambio quieres suspender el hilo por un tiempo específico utiliza `Thread.sleep()`, cabe mencionar que un `Thread.sleep` no puede ser notificado para reaunudar, por lo que siempre deberás esperar al que el timout finalice.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo No sabía que el sleep() consume recursos. Pensaba que se dormía a nivel de sistema operativo.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo  sleep() no tiene por qué consumir recursos. No hay nada en la descripción oficial de sleep() que diga que consume recursos. Que los consuma o no depende de lo optimizada que esté la máquina virtual de Java. Véase el código de mi respuesta como demostración.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo si `sleep(5000)` ocupase la CPU durante 5 segundos sin dejar hacer nada más a la CPU entonces mi programa que lanza 20000 sleeps concurrentes de a 5 segundos cada uno tardaría más de 27 horas en ejecutarse en una máquina de 4 núcleos. Pero tarda 10-13 segundos. Puedes ver un análisis del funcionamiento de `sleep` en http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml

Comment: @Antonio Tienes razón. Yo he tenido una comprensión equivocada entonces. Tu respuesta lo demuestra excelentemente. Me disculpo por la confusión provocada. Y los upvotes del caso