# Recolector de Basura G1 no libera memoria. Weblogic

Tags: java, jvm

Buen día a todos.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con el recolector de basura **G1**, bueno la verdad es la primera vez que tengo que tocar este tema. Sin embargo, les comento el problema:

Recientemente nuestro sistema en producción recibe muchas peticiones en "horas pico" por lo cual aumenta el espacio de consumo de memoria, después de estas horas picos pareciera que el recolector no alcanza a liberar espacio y cuando se vuelven a presentar las horas picos vuelve a aumentar pero desde el último punto en el cual no liberó memoria, lo cual hace que al cabo de unos días se llene la memoria y nos obligue a reiniciar.

Anexo imagen para mejor explicación.

[image: Gráfica]

Los datos que tengo en base al G1 son los siguientes:

```
-Xloggc:/ruta/gcsrv.log
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseG1GC
```

Comprendo que los usados son básicamente para pintar información del recolector, pero quisiera saber: **¿existe alguna sentencia que me ayude a mejorar el rendimiento de recolector?**. Es decir, **¿se puede liberar espacio más rápido con algún comando?** o bien algo relacionado para evitar que se llene la memoria.

Gracias.

Comment: Se ha resuelto el problema, más que problemas de rendimiento con el G1 o con las aplicaciones, se determinó un tema en nuestro servidor de aplicaciones Weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

El recolector por lo que tengo entendido trabaja cuando no está ocupado el procesador, por lo que la manera más sencilla podría ser limitar la cantidad de llamadas estableciendo un refresco menor de información o filtrando las réplicas en un espacio de tiempo para que pueda liberarse memoria.

Otra opción es revisar como se almacenan los datos, si estas usando variables fuera de los métodos se quedarán ahí ocupando memoria, pero si están dentro de métodos se deberían liberar al salir de la ejecución del método.

Para vigilar el estado de procesador, memoria y GC puedes usar un perfil de ejecución para ver de manera más clara lo que se consume en cada momento.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Verás al momento he estado haciendo pruebas con algunos desarrollos para monitorear cpu, memoria, conexiones a bd, jms, etc.. En algunos casos guarda mensajes en memoria (se borra en determinado tiempo), pero esto es parte de lo requerido. Para ver en tiempo real estoy utilizando el Jconsole. ¿Me podrías decir, cómo limitar la cantidad de llamadas estableciendo un refresco menor de información? ¿Esto lo podría hacer estableciendo algunas comandos en el GC?

Comment: Te recomiendo que heches un vistazo a esto [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374/cuál-es-la-diferencia-entre-wait-y-sleep-en-java).

Comment: Si nos puedes dar más pistas sobre el tipo de peticiones y datos que recibe la máquina y si los trata como listas, binarios, etc. Ayudaría mucho para tener más claro que puede ser lo que afecta al rendimiento. También podrías probar a combinar lo que describe en el enlace que te he dejado con las órdenes de GC, porque las llamadas reiterativas a GC pueden penalizar al rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Todas las aplicaciones deben de programarse de forma que no dependas del recolector de basura. `System.gc()` es la instrucción que SUGIERE que se ejecute el recolector de basura pero es eso, una sugerencia, por lo que puede ejecutarse en el momento de la invocación o mucho tiempo después.

Si tu aplicación va llenando la memoria y se va haciendo cada vez mas lenta es porque esta mal programada. Me refiero a que **abriste un recurso** como por ejemplo una conexión a base de datos **y no lo cerraste**. Esta situación se pone peor si abres el recurso dentro de un ciclo y el rendimiento se ve afectado.

Busca en tu código, te aseguro que tienes algo que se queda abierto, tal vez no lo cerraste o tal vez si pero lo hiciste en un lugar donde el código no entra y por eso se queda abierto.

Comment: Gracias por responder, veras las aplicaciones están bien programadas, ya que el código ya ha sido probado para todo tipo de cosa, una de ellas para ver las conexiones que abre, y no solo la de bd. En general sabemos que no guardan información una vez terminada su tarea, ya que los mensajes que guardan tienen un tiempo de expiración corto.