# Existe un equivalente de la función setTimeout de javascript en java

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy implementando una función en java que debe necesariamente esperar un tiempo, similar al setTimeout de javascript, que ejecuta una porción de código después de transcurrido un tiempo definido.

Por ejemplo el siguiente código de javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Por ahora, lo más cercano que he visto es crear un hilo y pausarlo:

```
thread.sleep
```

pero quisiera saber si hay una forma mas sencilla.

Comment: Si lo que requieres es pausar un proceso por un tiempo determinado, debes usar `sleep`, no conozco otra forma de realizar lo que pretendes. Tal vez hayas oído del método `wait`, pero el mismo se usa en otro contexto. Puedes leer un poco sobre esto en la siguiente [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-wait-y-sleep-en-java) del sitio. Saludos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html)

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          //***Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.

        };
    }, 3000); //Cada 3 segundos
```

o la clase [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) :

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //***Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.

    }
}, 3000); //Cada 3 segundos
```

Usando Java 9 puedes hacer uso de la clase [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#delayedExecutor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) :

```
CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).execute(() -> {
  //***Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.
});
```

Comment: Te agradecería algunas referencias de las librerías que mencionas en tu respuesta, para tener una base documentada. Por ahora, un +1 :)

Comment: @CesarLeonardoOchoaContreras No son librerías, son APIs parte de Java estándard, todas las instalaciones de JRE las soportan y todos los JDK recientes las tienen.

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de `Thread.sleep()` puedes probar usar un `javax.swing.Timer` para Java 8, y `delayedExecutor` para las nuevas versiones.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder, adicional a lo que comentas, siempre es bueno dejar un fragmento de código que resuelva la pregunta del OP. Puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Conozco dos clases java.util.Timer para agendar tareas en cualquier tipo de hilo; y si lo requieres para swing sería mejor javax.swing.Timer.

Te paso las ligas de la documentación de estas:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Es importante mencionar que los componentes swing solo se deben actualizar o invocar desde el hilo de eventos. Entonces si vas a mostrar algo mediante estos hay que usar el Timer del paquete swing ó establecer la sincronización con el hilo de eventos.

Para el ejemplo que muestras sería algo así:

```
java.awt.event.ActionListener listener = 
     new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
              javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HOLA");
         }
     };

new javax.swing.Timer(3000, listener).start();
```